# Functions on dense subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $G$ be a finitely generated dense subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f$ be a character on $G$.

In the situation I'm looking at $f$ is either $1$ or $-1$ at any point.

Function $f$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by setting it to $0$ outside $G$.
Is there any way to associate a distribution to $f$?
For example one could try to form an infinite sum of Diracs on $G$, or perhaps a limit of suitably normalized finite sums of Diracs?
Or maybe it can't be done in a meaningful way?

Any idea, reference or comment on how to deal with such objects is welcome.

Comment: Could you explicit a little bit what you need ? Why did you think of Dirac mass ? Because of the singular support ? You could have other examples of distributions like that.

Comment: Actually I've come to think there's probably no canonical way to do what I said. In the precise situation I was looking at, I realized that some additional information (essentially a set of generators) was playing a role and that was what gave meaning to the expression.